# SQLerror, getting error in group by function

Tags: sql, oracle

```
AUD_ID TITLE_ID DATES
------ -------- --------------------
   102        2 2021
   101        1 2021
   103        3 2022
```

```
select * from titles;
```

```
TITLE_ID TITLE                TYPE                 PRICE
-------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
       1 s1
       2 s2
       3 s2
```

```
select 
    titles.title,
    count(titleauth.aud_id) as ors,
    titleauth.dates 
from 
    titleauth 
join 
    titles on titleauth.title_id = titles.title_id 
group by 
    titleauth.dates;
```

> ERROR at line 1:
> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

```
select 
    count(titleauth.aud_id) as ors,
    titleauth.dates 
from 
    titleauth 
join 
    titles on titleauth.title_id = titles.title_id 
group by 
    titleauth.dates;
```

```
       ORS DATES
---------- --------------------
         2 2021
         1 2022
```

in first query where I included titles.title in select part getting error, but when I removed title select, it's working well. want to know the reason, please help.

Answer (score 0):

the column without aggregation function must be declared oin group by clause

```
    select 
        titles.title,
        count(titleauth.aud_id) as ors,
        titleauth.dates 
    from 
        titleauth 
    join 
        titles on titleauth.title_id = titles.title_id 
    group by 
        titleauth.dates, titles.title;
```

or you need  a (fake)  agggregation function on titles.title eg:

```
    select 
        min(titles.title),
        count(titleauth.aud_id) as ors,
        titleauth.dates 
    from 
        titleauth 
    join 
        titles on titleauth.title_id = titles.title_id 
    group by 
        titleauth.dates;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what ScaisEdge has already told you, appropriate aggregate function might be `listagg` as it lets you "list" all titles (note, though, that it has limit - the result can't be longer than 4000 characters, but - in this example, you're far from that).

Sample data in lines #1 - 11; query begins at line #12.

```
SQL> with
  2  titleauth (aud_id, title_id, dates) as
  3    (select 102, 2, 2021 from dual union all
  4     select 101, 1, 2021 from dual union all
  5     select 103, 3, 2022 from dual
  6    ),
  7  titles (title_id, title, type, price) as
  8    (select 1, 's1', null, null from dual union all
  9     select 2, 's2', null, null from dual union all
 10     select 3, 's3', null, null from dual
 11    )
 12  select
 13    listagg(t.title, ', ') within group (order by t.title) as list_of_titles,
 14    count(a.aud_id) as ors,
 15    a.dates
 16  from titleauth a join titles t on t.title_id = a.title_id
 17  group by a.dates;

LIST_OF_TITLES              ORS      DATES
-------------------- ---------- ----------
s1, s2                        2       2021
s3                            1       2022

SQL>
```